# Helm I try to put environment variables from env.yaml into existing env container in .yaml

Tags: json, dictionary, yaml, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

###### env.yaml

```
env:
  - name: VALUE1
    value: { { .Values.logging } }
  - name: VALUE2
    value: { { .Values.logging } }
  - name: VALUE3
    value: { { .Values.level } }
  - name: VALUE4
    value: { { .Values.level } }
```

###### statefulset.yaml

```
...
env:
  - name: VALUE5
    value: {{ .Values.secret | quote }}
  - name: VALUE6
    value: {{ .Values.filename }}
  {{- range .Values.env }}
  - name: {{ .name }}
    value: {{ .value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
...
```

Now I want to append the content of the **env.yaml** to the `env:` container of the **statefulset.yaml** with the `{{- range .Values.env }}`.
Now when I start the command:

```
helm install test-dev -f values.yaml -f env.yaml --namespace test-dev --create-namespace .
```

Than I get this error message:

```
Error: failed to parse env.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface ***]interface ***".Values.logging":interface ***(nil)***
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For env vars at the container level, it's generally done using `env` or `envFrom`. In your case, you can create a ConfigMap that holds the extra env vars then define `envFrom` and reference this ConfigMap. `envFrom` will take your ConfigMap and each key-value under `data` will become another env var.

In greater detail, your `stateful.yaml` will look something like:

```
...
env:
  - name: VALUE5
    value: {{ .Values.secret | quote }}
  - name: VALUE6
    value: {{ .Values.filename }}
envFrom:
  - configMapRef:
    name: envConfigs
...
```

Create a ConfigMap that looks something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: envConfigs
  namespace: default
data:
  {{- range .Values.env }}
  {{ .name }}: {{ .value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

One important thing to keep in mind is `env` takes precedence over `envFrom`. If you define a variable, say `example='123'`, under `env` AND within the ConfigMap also have `example='456'`, `example` will have value `123` when deployed to cluster. Hope this helps!